# Url routing getting confused between 2 routing rules

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I have two similar routing rules for my website. One for categories and another for brands

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "CategoryPage",
    pattern: "shop/{controller}/{id}/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}/{*categoryName}",
    defaults: new { area = "shop", controller = "category", action = "index" });

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "BrandPage",
    pattern: "shop/{controller}/{id}/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}/{*brandName}",
    defaults: new { area = "shop", controller = "brand", action = "index" });
```

All that is different is the controller and the brand / category name.

my urls should look like this.

```
shop/Category/79/1/80/Clothing-Accessories
shop/Brand/79/1/80/my-brand
```

But the second routing rule in my list always shows up as

```
shop/Brand/159/1/80?brandName=Anchor-Crew
```

I thought with a different controller name it could tell which one to use but that does not seem to be the case. One possible solution is I give them both similar names such as 'slug'.

Update to include controllers

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromRoute] long id, int pageNumber, int pageSize, string brandName)
    {
        PaginatedList<Product> products = GetProducts(id, pageNumber, pageSize);
        Brand brand = await _brandService.GetAsync(id);

public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromRoute]long id, int pageNumber, int pageSize, string categoryName)
    {
        Category? category = await _categoryService.Get(id, true);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the Controller code for the first and the second routes respectively? It seems like the `{*brandName}` for the second route is configured as a query parameter instead of the route parameter.

Comment: I have included the signatures of my controllers.  Just to mention if I flip my routing rules around the brand routing will work and the categories won't.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following quotes from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#conventional-routing) are applicable here:

> Conventional routing is used with controllers and views. The default route:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

> This mapping:

> - Is based on the controller and action names only.
> - Isn't based on namespaces, source file locations, or **method parameters**.

Routing does not take in account action parameter names, so from the routing point of view you have defined two routes which are the same when only segments are used.

Conventional routes are applied in order of definition (see the corresponding warning in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#url-matching)):

> `MapControllerRoute` and `MapAreaRoute` automatically assign an order value to their endpoints based on the order they are invoked. This simulates long-time behavior of controllers without the routing system providing the same guarantees as older routing implementations.

so changing the route definition order has the observed effect of switching the selected controller.

It seems that providing last parameter as query string parameter lets the routing to select the correct controller (can't find in the docs why).

You can try using "more specific" route for the earlier declared route to match needed controller explicitly:

```
// remove controller template param and hardcode controller 
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "CategoryPage",
    pattern: "shop/category/{id}/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}/{*categoryName}",
    defaults: new { area = "shop", controller = "category", action = "index" });

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "BrandPage",
    pattern: "shop/{controller}/{id}/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}/{*brandName}",
    defaults: new { area = "shop", controller = "brand", action = "index" });
```

Comment: That didn't work. In the end I just had I one route as they are both to similar and both go through that. Not exactly what I wanted but now both work perfectly. Will add my answer soon